# Rounding the nearest number ending in 90

Tags: php

*I apologize in advance for the wrong question. English is not my native language.*

I want to write a function that will round up or down to 90, depending on which is closer.

Unfortunately, I'm not a techie and I don't have enough brains to come up with a formula)

For example, there is a number: 11210

The nearest number is 11190, which means the function should return 11190, not 11290.

P.S. ChatGPT job failed.
Tried via `ceil($num/90)*90`
It turns out nonsense

Comment: You're so close. ChatGPT gave you the answer, and it's definitely not nonsense: it's just off by one, which you can quite easily fix yourself by using "that other common rounding function".

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: There's also the rounding up _or_ down. ChatGPT is a bad advisor, because it's answer is only as good as its input.

Comment: exactly: it's a bad advisor, and you need to correct it if you use it.

Comment: It seems that I got `round($number / 100, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP) * 100 - 10;`

Comment: But in this case, what do you mean with "it needs to round up or down to 90"? Do you need _factors_ of 90? (in which case 11210 will be 11160) or do you want to round to "the nearest number ending in 90"? Because those are wildly different things.

Comment: the nearest number ending in 90 - edit my question. Thanks)

Comment: In that case a hint is "rounding V to the nearest 90 is the same as rounding (V-90) to the nearest 100, then adding 90"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, the answer comes when you have already asked it. Thanks everyone, thought out the solution:

```
function roundToNearestNinety($number) {
    return round($number / 100) * 100 - 10;
}

echo roundToNearestNinety(11130); // 11090
echo roundToNearestNinety(11150); // 11190
```

Comment: note that [a per the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round) the precision already defaults to 0, and the rounding method is already half_round_up. There is no reason to put those in your code.